# How much would a third season of SGU cost to produce?

Tags: production, stargate, stargate-universe

I'm entertaining a dream in which I win €140,000,000 in [the EuroMillions draw](http://www.euro-millions.com/) and use it to fund the return of unfairly-cancelled shows.

Using any available figures, how much would a third season of SGU cost to produce, to roughly the same *stellar* level of production quality as was enjoyed by the first two seasons?

Bear in mind that some overheads for set construction and the like, not usually borne out per episode, or even per season, would now have to be covered for the first time since the first season premiere.

Comment: How about to start a campaing on kickstarter.com?
If an episode cost about 3 million, if 300.000 people donate 10 dollars per episode (i will be the first in line), that way we can have SG-U back again! :) Anyone interested on contacting the producers and start the campaing?

Comment: @Sabastian: OK yes but we'd need the whole season for the reasons that sarge_smith lays out. Say at a minimum ten episodes (_absolute_ minimum) we need 3 million people. That's hard to do with a kickstarter campaign.

Comment: I'm glad to see I'm not the only one who has this dream :D. One of the writers of this same show also had another show called Dark Matter, but it was cancelled before a Season 4/5 could be produced. Problem is, in addition to money, the actors contracts expired. On top of having the budget you might have to pay them a little than before to get them to come back. Who knows if they will come back, most already have other shows and movies lined up.

Comment: @Nexusfactor: Yeah it's vanishingly unlikely now sadly. Dark Matter was an attempt to make a similar show on a much smaller budget (and without pissing off the SG1/SGA stalwarts who sabotaged SGU out of spite), but IMO it showed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't seem to find a actual sourced number but most of the places I checked had a budget of between 1.5 and 3 million per episode. There was no budget jump between seasons 1 and 2 so you would need between 30 and 60 million to produce the normal 20 episode season.

Your sets are normally amortized out over the course of the season as a part of the pre-filming production work. In other words, it is included in that 1.5 to 3 mil episode number.

A final note: You would be unable to film single episodes for that value. The numbers presented here are the the "economy of scale" numbers that you would get by funding an entire season. If you tried to make a bunch of individual episodes, you would be paying some costs multiple times, resulting in a 25 to 50% increase in price (Depending on shooting schedule, your talent costs and pre and post productions cost). You would also have to pay for a license that would have to be negotiated and I have no way of determining how much that would cost you, beyond expensive.

Comment: Excellent; that's about what I expected. We're good to go, then! All I need now is that jackpot. _Shall we wait on the porch?_

Comment: Lest we forget, most of the actors are already committed up to 2018. Getting them back at the same time would require nothing short of a miracle.

Comment: @user7812: Only two years to go.

Comment: @user7812: Right, let's do it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _Still waiting on that porch I see._